# Unable to access Jaeger app running in EKS Cluster pod

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, jaeger

I have an EKS cluster in which I created a deployment, service, and ingress respectively  using the below declarative code

I can see my pods are running and ingress is also in place but how can I access the Jaeger app running in the pod in my EKS Cluster?

I tried to access the Jaeger app using the URL  jaeger-dev.cloud.com but nothing showing in the browser

```
# jaeger-deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jaeger
  namespace: telemetry
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/fargate-profile: telemetry
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jaeger
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jaeger
        fargate: "yes"
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: "eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "fargate"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
      containers:
      - name: jaeger
        image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 16686
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jaeger
  namespace: telemetry
spec:
  selector:
    app: jaeger
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 16686

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-jaeger-ingress
  namespace: telemetry
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-07558efdd4dfljksdhf , subnet-0f7c5a25sdfsdfsd
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.1.1/12, 192.168.0.0/16
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443},{"HTTP":80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:818714027071:certificate/615246d7-2b32-4523-sjkg-sdfkjhdskfsd
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: environment=dev
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=300
spec:
  rules:
  - host: jaeger-dev.cloud.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name:  jaeger
            port:
              number: 16686
```

I have run the command "kubectl get pods -n telemetry" and I get the below output

```
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jaeger-5fdd777b97-gszc4   1/1     Running   0          15h
```

I have run the command "kubectl get svc -n telemetry" and I get the below output

```
NAME     TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
jaeger   NodePort   172.20.89.211   <none>        80:30953/TCP   15h
```

I have run the command "kubectl get deployments -n telemetry" and I get the below output

```
NAME     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
jaeger   1/1     1            1           17h
```

I have run the command "kubectl get ingress -n telemetry" and I get the below output

```
NAME                 CLASS    HOSTS                          ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
dev-jaeger-ingress   <none>   jaeger-dev.cloud.com             80      17h
```